# C++11 for windows XP SP1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, windows-xp

I want to write code using C++11 to work on windows XP SP1.
Naturally I want to use visual studio, 
But versions 2012\2013 don't support XP SP1
And version 2010 doesn't support C++11

I'd rather have the VS2013 c++11 features, But the features in VS2012 can suffice too.

Thanks

Comment: Both VS2012 and VS2013 support WindowsXP if you select the appropriate *Platform Toolset*. Not sure if that support includes SP1 though.

Comment: I loved XP too, but maybe it's time to let it go? (I joke, I know it's not always possible).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, C++ language doesn't have anything to do with the OS. The compiler/linker is supposed to produce a binary, which the target CPU will understand. The OS/kernel/libraries etc. do some later. You may use other compiler (GCC, CLang) on Windows, that would produce executable that may run on Windows XP.

Or, you may *try* to build a static library (.LIB) using Visual Studio 2012/13. The library shouldn't be using any runtime library (VC runtime, for example), but should have your code only. If it doesn't work, try using other compiler to produce DLL or LIB.